# Where are save files located? (Unturned V2.2.0)

Tags: unturned

I want to delete my local save file for the map PEI but I cannot find the file anywhere. In earlier versions, the saves were stored in the registry but it is not the case anymore.

So where are the save files located so I can delete them and start from scratch.

Comment: This is an interesting question - seems to be a bit of a mystery. Apparently it used to be saved in the registry, but this has now changed: http://unturned.wikia.com/wiki/Unturned_save_file

Comment: A new mystery has appeared, who will be the lucky one to discover the great secret?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "savegame" is still stored in the registry under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Smartly Dressed Games\Unturned
```

They relevant keys begin with

> barricades
>
> clothes
>
> inventory

and a lot of others, mixed with your normal settings.

I have monitored the app with Handle, Process Explorer and some other security software I have access to and did not find any evidence of the game spawning any file handles that would indicate it saves somewhere else.

After deleting the registry entries and relaunching the game, the same entries reappeared:

[image: Screenshot of the savegame]

Comment: So I only need to delete all entries, right?

Comment: That should be enough, yes.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Its weird that I saw on the wiki that it wasnt stored in the registry anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to windows search and write "regedit" Then go "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" Then Go to "Software" Then find "Smartly Dressed Games"
Then you find Unturned if you wanna start at begin you need to delete "Smartly Dressed Games" Folder.